# Vim-latex Incorrectly Expanding Environment

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I just began using `vim-latex` and started with their [tutorial](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite-quickstart/index.html).

Following the instructions on [this](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite-quickstart/lsq-insert-environment.html) page, I type `eqnarray` followed by `F5`, but instead of getting the described

```
\begin{eqnarray}
   \label{}<++>
\end{eqnarray}<++>
```

I get

```
\begin{eqnarray}

  \label{<++>}
\end{eqnarray}<++>
```

This is my complete file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[sumlimits,]{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}

  \label{<++>}
\end{eqnarray}<++>

\end{document}
```

Is this is a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `eqnarray` anyway: it's one of the weakest points in LaTeX. Use `align`, instead. I don't know whether Vim treats this one correctly, but the main point is that `eqnarray` is buggy.

Comment: @egreg: Same issue when I try the expansion with `align`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is the expected behaviour in vim-latexsuite and it may just be a bug in the quickstart tutorial.

If you want to change to get this

```
\begin{eqnarray}
   \label{}<++>
\end{eqnarray}<++>
```

with the cursor in between the label brackets, you can define the following variable and then type eqnarray followed by `F5`.

```
let g:Tex_Env_eqnarray = "\\begin{eqnarray}\<CR>\label{<++>}<++>\<CR>\\end{eqnarray}"
```

This should work also for other environments like `align` using instead the `Tex_Env_align` variable.