# How to add custom environment in latex-suite

Tags: vim, vim-latex

Latex-suite provides short keys to make working with environments like `equation` easier in VIM. For example, I like to press `<F5>` to change the environment.

One of the environments that I find missing is `align`; another one is `subequations`. I would like to add these as new environments. How can I do that?

Comment: These short keys depends to the text editor. What editor you have adopted? Usually you can easily add new short but the procedure is different for each software

Comment: @marchetto Latex-Suite works for vim.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not know Latex-suite.

Comment: @marchetto thank you for asking. I added it to my question. Maybe I can add the vim tag too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of the <kbd>F5</kbd> list is encoded in the `g:Tex_PromptedEnvironments` variable in vim, adding (changing and expanding the list of environments as appropriate)

```
let g:Tex_PromptedEnvironments='align,align*,itemize,enumerate'
```

into `.vimrc` changes the list of prompted environments, allowing customisation according to needs.  Any environments defined in the tex file itself will also be appended to the list though this may require restarting vim.

If adding an environment which requires something beyond the `\begin{foo} \end{foo}` and is not recognised by vim-latex by default, this can be customised with the `g:Tex_Env_foo` variable as described in this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127208/ and in the vim-latex manual http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-macros.html#Tex_Env_name

To set up the itemize environment for example (though this should already be recognised and sensibly processed by vim-latex alongside a number of environments outside those listed by default in `g:Tex_PromptedEnvironments`) the following example can be used

```
 let g:Tex_Env_itemize="\\begin{itemize}\<CR>\\item <++>\<CR>\\end{itemize}"
```